# Erro ao Inserir icon num Jmenu

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

Bom Dia a todos,

Estou com um projeto java usando a IDE Netbeans 12.0, ao tentar inserir imagens como icon no Menu Item e rodar o formulário me apresenta a exception nullpointerexception, segue abaixo como está o designer do form

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E segue abaixo o erro que ocorre:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at view.FrmTelaInicial.initComponents(FrmTelaInicial.java:90)
    at view.FrmTelaInicial.<init>(FrmTelaInicial.java:22)
    at view.FrmTelaInicial$3.run(FrmTelaInicial.java:220)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Segue abaixo a linha de código gerada automaticamente pela IDE referente ao erro **at view.FrmTelaInicial.initComponents(FrmTelaInicial.java:90)** que acredito ser a causa dos meus problemas.

`jMenu1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/clientes.png"))); // NOI18N`

Sou iniciante mais pelo que pude perceber analisando o erro é que, talvez a imagem do ícone não está sendo encontrada mesmo indicando o caminho para instanciação do ImageIcon. E que quando vai compilar o formulário o ImageIcon está com valor null e gerando a Exception.

Segue print do pacote onde a imagem está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda do meu professor do curso consegui resolver o problema clicando em Clear and Builder. Fazendo isso não deu mais o erro.